# How to retrieve query data output from Dynamodb using Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am having difficulty to understand where is my query stored in which array variable. I know the "var params" contains all the query conditions and "db.query" will perform the actual query action. But how do I get my query result which match my search condition?

At the end, I want to pass my query output parameters (title, postedby) to html or jade for display so I need to understand where all the query data are stored at first place and how to retrieve them. Some sample code to demo this part would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
var params = {
TableName: tablename,
AttributesToGet: [
'title',
'postedBy'
],
Limit: 20,
ScanIndexForward: true,
KeyConditions: { /* required */
    key : {
        ComparisonOperator: 'EQ', /* required */
            AttributeValueList: [
            {
                'N' : 'some value'
            }
            /* more items */
    },
},
};

db.query(params, function(err, data) {
if (err) {
    console.log('show error here');
} else {
    console.log('Success');
}
});
```

I found out that all my query data is stored inside "data" from function(err, data). But i am having problem passing "data" to the following export function which later can be used as a local variable inside my webpage. Then I realized the "data" part is always empty {} inside export function even i am sure the above db.query can return the right result. So i believe somehow the export.list function is executed before the db.query happen so I am not getting any data assigned. How can I overcome this part? Thanks.

```
exports.list = function(req, res){
  res.render('post', {title:'Title', posts : data });
  console.log("Result: %j", data);
};
```

Note: Console.log("Result: ", data) is showing {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Use the callback function due to the nature of javascript. Thanks.